# Is it a bad idea to use that huge App_Browsers mobile.browser file?

Tags: asp.net, browser, mobile-website, browser-detection

I was having trouble detecting mobile device capabilities correctly in ASP.NET 2.0.

Then, I ran across this project:

http://mdbf.codeplex.com/

Basically, it is an xml file (.browser file) containing definitions for lots of mobile device browsers. The problem is this file is about 350k lines long. Since I'm checking parameters on every page request, I'm worried that using such a large file could slow down server responses.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDBF is great and has no issues after applciation start up (when the file gets parsed and cached). As long as you don't have resource issues on your server which mean that the file will need to be regularly reloaded you'll be fine.

However! [MDBF is no longer supported](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=219552) and won't be updated further. Consider using http://51degrees.codeplex.com/ instead.

Comment: I implemented this system on my companies website when I deployed a mobile site. It is only used for sending mobile browsers to the mobile site (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice), but it doesn't slow anything down at all. With MDBF dying off as Matt said, I am considering something using [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: 51degree uses WURFL under the hood.  When I just want to detect if a browser is mobile I use my own port of http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/ but there's also http://detectmobilebrowser.com/ which is free and comes with a C# version by default.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely quick enough. I have a site using that database and the page load times are sub-second.